# Java - Constraining method parameter in an interface to the implementing class

Tags: java, generics, parameters, interface

I have an interface that is implemented by other classes. But I need one of the parameters of one methods of the interface to be restricted to the class implementing the interface.

One option to achieve what I need would be parametrizing the interface.

```
public interface Profile<T> {
     public void aggregate(T p);
}

public class SpecificProfile implements Profile<SpecificProfile> {
    public void aggregate(SpecificProfile p) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve it without using generics?

Comment: What don't you like about this approach?

Comment: Generics are clean and awesome

Comment: Looks pretty clean to me :)

Comment: the only thing you could change is `Profile<T extends Profile>` to be sure that the parameter has to be a subclass of your interface.

Comment: The problem is that it would allow something like:
`public class SpecificProfile implements Profile<AnotherProfile>`. This has its own pros but I am trying to enforce the parameter type to be the implementing class. What I wanted to know if there's some other way to enforce it from the interface class itself rather than from the implementation.

Comment: @KevinEsche: But that does not give any type safety benefit. If someone wants to implement a `Profile` with `T` that is not a `Profile` in a type-safe way; what's wrong with that? It doesn't interfere with you implementing your `Profile` with `T` that extends `Profile`. Also, you are using a raw type.

Comment: I would use `Profile<T extends Profile<T>>`, but that would be it.

Comment: @KevinEsche You would use `Profile` as a raw type in the generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to declare "one of the parameters of one methods of the interface to be restricted to the class implementing the interface" in Java.